# How to minimally hide the location of a file with JWPlayer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jwplayer

Can't seem to find anything on the JWPlayer web site about this. We are using JWPlayer to play our video files that are stored on Amazon S3. Everything works. The file is loaded onto the player and the video plays as expected.

However, I would like to know how to hide the path to the file name. I'm not trying to stop any user from downloading this. I know thats impossible. I'm just trying to obscure the path to the file.

I looked around, and found that TwitVid loads the file with a token. As seen below:

```
file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitvid.com%2FplayVideo_PYZFR%2Ftoken_1318603680
```

How can this be done with JWPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

I too have just been toying with JWPlayer and found an approach that does look quite practical and reasonable.  Check out more [details here as well as the source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/416) — this can easily be applied to your AmazonS3 paths.

This past weekend I've designed and S3 uploader to API and will most likely take this approach towards URI obfuscation.

Comment: Hmmm, currently using Carrierwave ( https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave ) instead of Paperclip. Couldn't find a similar feature on Carrierwave... Do you otherwise know how this can be achieved with Carrierwave?

Comment: It's a general enough approach that you could apply to Carrierwave, possibly.  I guess you'd need to look at Paperclip's interpolation method and see how you can carry that around to Carrierwave.